# Stock Price - Expectation Log of Stock Price

Tags: statistics, brownian-motion, finance

One of stock price model is GBM, which is
$$ dS_t = {\mu}S_tdt + {\sigma}S_tdW $$
with the solution of the model is
$$ S_t = S_0e^{(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + {\sigma}W_t} $$
with $ ln(\frac{S_t}{S_0}) \sim N\Big{(}(r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t, \sigma^2t\Big{)} $ and $ r $ is risk-free interest rate.

I have several question

1. How to prove that $ \mathbf{E}\Big{(}ln(\frac{S_t}{S_0})\Big{)} = (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t $?
2. Why $ \mu $ is equal to $ r $?

Note: I have succeeded to prove $ var\Big{(}ln(\frac{S_t}{S_0})\Big{)} = \sigma^2t$ by using induction.

Comment: It looks trivial from what yiu have. $ln (S/S_0) $ is normally distributed. Its expected value therefore is the mean of this normal distribution, which you can read from inside the bracket $~N (,)$.

Comment: Yes I know the mean is the first part inside the bracket, but aside from that, how do we prove that its expected value is $(r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t$?

Comment: How do you find the expected value of a general random variable? Use definition of the expected value (here you need to integrate $xf (x) $, where $f $ is the distribution function (over appropriate domain.)

Comment: This question is fine here, but maybe also try quant.stackexchange.com for financial math problems